# SQL выбрать N-TOP строк с разными условиями

Tags: sql, select

Есть база SQL на много тысяч строк
Нужно сравнивая столбцы с числовыми значениями выбрать, например, 1000 строк.
500 строк где значение столбца А > значение столбца Б, 300 строк где А = Б и 200 где А < Б.
Кроме этого 600 строк должны быть с суммой значений столбцов А + Б >=10, а 400 строк где А + Б < 10.
Если делать так

```
select top(500) *
frome base
where a>b
union
select top(600) *
frome base
where (a+b)>=10
```

то я уже получаю строк где a>b больше чем мне нужно

Вопрос как составить запрос чтобы на выходе получить нужное количество строк с выполнением всех условий?

Comment: Отдельные подзапросы по каждому из условий (c исключением пересечения подвыборок), и UNION ALL.

Comment: 1. Укажите какая именно база данных используется. top конечно намекает на ms sql-server, но вдруг еще в какой он бывает. 2. Вам надо именно 1000 записей с примерным процентым распределением подходящих условий ? Что если по условию A > Б есть только 10 записей, значит ли это что 990 надо распределить между остальными условиями в соотношении 3/2 ?

Comment: 3. Вторая группа условий должна быть равномерно распределена среди записей по первым условиям, т.е. если у нас 500 строк A > Б то среди них должно быть 300 строк А + Б >=10 или допустимо неравномерное распределение вплоть до того что все 500 строк A > Б окажутся с А + Б >=10

Comment: Mike
1) ms sql-server
2) Нужно 1000 записей с точным процентным распределением.
Если А > Б только 10 записей, то остальных записей должно стать тоже меньше: 3 строки А = Б, 2 строки А < Б.
3) Вторая группа условий должна быть равномерно распределена: 500 строк A > Б окажутся с А + Б >=10    так быть не может

Answer (score 0):

Начать можно с того, что явно разбить записи на группы по условиям. Определим 2 набора групп: mm_g по первым условиям A <=> B, получаем 3 группы, первой пусть будет та где A < B. Второй набор групп s_g - две группы по значению суммы A+B. Далее явно определим количество записей для всех комбинаций групп mm_g и s_g. После чего остается выбрать нужное количество записей по каждой комбинации условий. Получается примерно так:

```
select *
  from (
      select *, row_number() over(partition by mm_g, s_g order by id) RN
        from (
           select *,
                  case when A < B then 1 when A=B then 2 else 3 end as mm_g,
                  case when a + b >= 10 then 1 else 2 end as s_g
             from test
        ) y
   ) X,
   (values(1, 1, 200*0.6), (1, 2, 200*0.4),
          (2, 1, 300*0.6), (2, 2, 300*0.4),
          (3, 1, 500*0.6), (3, 2, 500*0.4)
    ) as C(mm_g, s_g, cnt)
 where x.mm_g=C.mm_g and x.s_g=C.s_g and x.RN <= C.cnt
```

Если действительно необходимо соблюсти условие описанное в комментариях к вопросу как 2 (пропорционально уменьшить все выборки, в случае если в одной из них недостаточно записей). То можно выборку `X` заключить в with, получить из нее суммарное количество записей по группам и пересчитать количества в выборке `C` согласно этим количествам.